# PCmanFM prompt "This file is executable. Do you want to execute it?" when double clicking a file

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

I use Lubuntu. I downloaded a `.tar.bz2` of [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), and extracted it. When I double click the `sublime_text` executable, a window pops up with "This file is executable. Do you want to execute it?" message. How can I launch Sublime Text without that prompt?

Comment: How exactly do you launch the program? Do you use a launcher, a terminal command, something else?

Comment: Double click from PCManFM (default graphical file manager in Lubuntu). Fresh installed OS.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the problem non-vague terms. Please correct if anything is not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is the way PCmanFM deals with binary files, but not only PCmanFM. In Linux, a binary file is meant to be run, instead of doubleclicked. For example, in your case, `./sublime_text` would be the way to run it. That said, doubleclicking is convinient, so you can create a custom launcher on the desktop or in the menu.

In a terminal window, run `leafpad SublimeText.desktop`, and paste in the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/home/vitaly/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Icon/128x128/sublime_text.png
Name=Sublime Text
Comment=Sublime Text       
Categories=Applications
Exec=/home/vitaly/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
```

I've assumed that your username is `vitaly`, and that you've extracted the program to your home folder. You'll need to correct the paths if that's not the case.

Comment: I did as you told and when I try run created shortcut I get this message: "Failed to execute child process "/home/vitaly/Sublime-Text-2" (Permission denied)

Comment: Oh, sorry - I just made a mistake when writing this .desktop file. All work now, thank you!

Comment: Most welcome. Glad I could help.